# Pandas - Look up if a value exists else keep the same value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df1 like this,

```
id gender
1  m
2  f
3  u
4
```

and I have a lookup dataframe like this,

```
lookupinputcol  lookupoutputcol
m                male
f                female
```

and I want to generate a new column in my df1 like this

```
id gender lookup_gender
1  m       male
2  f       female
3  u       u
4
```

joins/merges/concat would help me with this, but it would not give me the value of 'u' in row 3 and '' in row 4 as that record was not in the lookup table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) or [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) by dictionary or `Series`:

```
d = dict(zip(df1['lookupinputcol'], df1['lookupoutputcol']))
#alternative solution 
#d = df1.set_index('lookupinputcol')['lookupoutputcol']
df['lookup_gender_new'] = df['gender'].map(d).fillna(df['gender'])
```

Or:

```
df['lookup_gender_new'] = df['gender'].replace(d)
```

Comment: @Sid29 - Changed column to `lookup_gender_new`, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for helping with this in a way that I can understand and re-use it

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively create the `dict` as per jezrael's answer:

```
d = dict(zip(df1['lookupinputcol'], df1['lookupoutputcol']))
```

Then use `apply`:

```
df['lookup_gender'] = df.apply(lambda x: d.get(x['gender'],x['gender]),axis=1)
```